Coordinates of the centers of the insphere and circumsphere
Suppose we are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space and we have four non-coplanar and non-collinear points, $(x_a, y_a, z_a)$, $(x_b, y_b, z_b)$, $(x_c,y_c, z_c)$, and $(x_d, y_d, z_d)$. How does one determine the coordinates of the center of the circumsphere and the center of the insphere of these points, and what are the formulae for these points?

The circumcircle of three of the points lies in the surface of the circumsphere, so drop perpendiculars through two of the circumcentres and intersect them.
